# Java Change Calculation

Tags: java

Please I got a change algorithm calculation which adds up instead of subtracting the amount paid by the user . i want the program to be able to deduct the amount paid from the textbox using a set of currency buttons and when the amount is over paid, a balance should be returned back to the user. it instead adds up each time i click on any of the currency buttons using the message box. Thanks

These are the currency buttons:

```
      private void tenPoundButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    amountToPay -= 1000;
    calculate(amountToPay);
}                                              

private void twentyPoundButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    amountToPay -= 2000;
    calculate(amountToPay);
}                                                 

private void fiftyPoundButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    amountToPay -= 5000;
    calculate(amountToPay);
}
```

this is the change algorithm :

```
    public void calculate(double amount) {

    if (amount > 0) {
        amountPaidTextBox.setText(pounds.format(amount/100));
    }
    else {
        amountPaidTextBox.setText("");

        if (amount < 0){
            double change;
            change = -amount;

            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Your change is " + pounds.format(change / 100)

                    + coins (change), 
                    "change", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Thank you, Exact Amount");
        }
    }
}



      String coins(double change) {
    String answer = ":";

    if (change >= 4000) // give two £20 note change
    {
        answer += "\nTwo £20 note";
        change -= 4000;
    }
    if (change >= 2000) // give a £20 note change
    {
        answer += "\nOne £20 note";
        change -= 2000;
    }
    if (change >= 1500) // give £15 note change, a £10 note and a £5 note.
    {
        answer += "\nOne £10 note,\nOne £5 note ";
        change -= 1500;
    }
    if (change >= 1000) // give a £10 note change
    {
        answer += "\nOne £10 note";
        change -= 1000;
    }
    if (change >= 500) // give a £5 note change
    {
        answer += "\nOne £5 note";
        change -= 500;
    }
```

Comment: This is not clear.  What is an example input and output, and what were you expecting?

Comment: An example of an input is when a user buys several products at a certain amount e.g 10.30 and the user clicks on any of the currency buttons to pay e.g 50P, 10P, £2, £1 instead of deducting the amount paid it adds up the currency button that was clicked e.g if the user clicks on 50P, 20P, £1 it adds it up to £1.70 using a message box instead of deducting £1.70 from 10.30

Comment: Working with floating point types and monetary values becomes funny more sooner than later... use a `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem.

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Your change is " + pounds.format(change / 100)+ coins (change), "change", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

while calling `coins(double change)` you are passing negative parameters.

Suppose if uyou want to deduct 2000 then you are passing `count=-2000`

`-2000/100 = -20`

so after the above statement is executed you are getting negative value. please let me know if you want more explanation.